# Export JSP to Word With External CSS

Tags: html, css, jsp

I am trying to export a JSP generated document webpage to Microsoft Word. In the web browser, everything looks great. However, when I change

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java" import="java.util.*, java.text.*;" errorPage="" %>
```

to

```
<%@ page contentType="application/msword; charset=windows-1252" language="java" import="java.util.*, java.text.*;" errorPage=""  %>
```

The page *will* try to open in word, but it will lose all of its styling.

I am linking to few external style sheets, but these are not picked up in the Word Document.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/common.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/general.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/headerfooter.css"/>
```

I have also tried linking href to the direct location on the server. This also did not work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/app/css/common.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/app/css/general.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/app/css/headerfooter.css"/>
```

Finally, I have tried to move the styling inside the JSP. However, this has not worked when it comes to exporting the document to word, either.

How can I export a JSP to Microsoft Word and have it retain styling?

Comment: Lol. Yes because conversion to Word is as simple as changing the content-type header. Seriously? Are HTML documents equivalent to Word documents? Lookup Apache POI. Its a library to actually create a real Word document.

Comment: @developerwjk While I appreciate the input, the condescending tone does nothing to help. As a matter of fact, Word handles HTML documents very well and, in my particular case, it is much easier to create an HTML document than it is to deal with Apache POI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linking to external styling sheets will cause the JSP to lose formatting. The solution is to embed the styling inside the JSP. While I mention above that I did that, it contained formatting errors that, once fixed, displayed the styling properly in Microsoft Word.

Additionally, here is a good resource for adding Word specific styling to your document such as orientation, page margins, and embedded images:

http://sebsauvage.net/wiki/doku.php?id=word_document_generation